# load balancing and socket.js

Tags: php, sockets, load-balancing

Currently I'm working on a project is about chat system between client and agent by using socket.js and PHP.
Recently, received confirmation from client is client server will have load balancer to balance to different server.
Like picture below.
[image]

I'm found out an issue from this setup.

**Agent A** is connected to **Server B**, but **Client A** is connected to **Server A**, so **Client A** can't communicate with **Agent A**.

How can I solve this problem by using programming way?

**PS:**

1. **Client is not allow me to edit any server config file or settings.**
2. **Client server is linux server.**

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

we have a similar problem. Right now we have a solution, but it is most likely not the best. When we start our 2 socket servers on 2 different servers, then each server also creates a socketconnection to the other socket server. So each socket server is also a client of the other socket server. When Socket Server A receives a communication it sends it to all connected users AND it also broadcasts it to Socket Server B, and that one sends it then to all connected users again.

Another solution is a Publish/Subscribe broker, like you can find in that link here https://hackernoon.com/scaling-websockets-9a31497af051.

Hope that helps somehow.